# Inacccurate std function in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, math, statistics

```
pd.Series([1612.154152]*12).std()
>> 2.374840586831367e-13
```

The standard deviation here should be zero.
Additionally, if I use instead rolling:

```
 pd.Series([1612.154152]*12).rolling(12).std()
```

I do get 0 (the correct answer).

This happened on both pandas 1.4 and 1.3 (latest releases)

Any ideas why? or ideas to extract correctly the std without using rolling?

Comment: `2e-13` is very close to `0`, and can be regarded as / caused by floating point error. The difference between the rolling std and normal std might be due to the different accumulation algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correct. It's problem with floating point numbers.
When you want to get result of operation based on floating point numbers, your result will be only estimated. Computer computes in binary way and give you result in decimal. Computing floating point numbers is so hard in binary way and you never get exact result.
Try to replace decimal floating point numbers to binary and conversely and you understand why it is so hard.

This easy code in python is great example:

```
print(.1 + .2 == .3)
print(.1 + .2)
```

Your result will be:

```
False 0.30000000000000004
```

So your result is correct.
You can for example use round().

```
Round(pd.Series([1612.154152]*12).std(),10)
```

Probably in rolling method is already round or something like this during computing.